# How to encrypt images with python

Tags: python, image, encryption

Preface: this is required for a class, I know ECB should not be used.

I am trying to encrypt images using AES and then display the images

Steps needed:
Read the image,
Convert to byte object,
Pad the bytes,
Encrypt the bytes,
Convert back to image object,
Save as image file

This is my code right now:

```
from PIL import Image
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

img = Image.open("photo.jpg")
img.tobytes()

key = '0123456789abcdef'
mode = AES.MODE_ECB
encryptor = AES.new(key, mode)

img.frombytes("RGB")
```

At this point I am stuck. I am getting a "not enough image data" error on the line "img.frombytes("RGB"), and am also stuck at the part to pad the bytes

Comment: Why are you trying to visualize the encrypted document? If it had an image format, that would be leaking information, wouldn't it?

Comment: Once you encrypt the image file, it just becomes a big pile of random bytes. Turning that back into an image would be however you would interpret a list of numbers (or bytes) as an image.

Comment: I am doing this as a project in class.. not for a production environment

Comment: You're calling `img.tobytes()` but then doing nothing with the returned bytes!  Shouldn't you give these to the encryptor?  Also you're passing the bytes of "RGB" to `img.frombytes()` instead of giving it some data bytes (presumably decrypted bytes?)

Answer (score 0):

So I needed a way to transfer files in the form of images (don't ask me why), if you just want to transfer text you can maybe create a txt file.

This is probably not exactly the best solution to the question as you probably want a way to hide data inside an existing image but I would like anyway to share the code in case it will help someone sometime somewhere.

*Basically this will create an image with a size dependent on the file size and will put a sequence of 3 bytes in one pixel (RGB)*

So I  wrote a small folder2ImageEncoder.py
(it will encrypt all the data that is located in a folder named "**files**" by default)

```py
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path
encryptedImagesFolder = 'encryptedImagesFolder' 

Path(f"./{encryptedImagesFolder}").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
newLine = b'\new\n\rL'


def encode_data_to_image(data: bytes, imagePath: str):
    data += b'FINISH_OF_DATA'

    data = str(
        {
            'path': imagePath,
            'data': data
        }
    )
    data = data.encode()
    n = int((len(data)/3)**0.5) + 1
    print(n, len(data))

    img = Image.new('RGB', (n, n))
    # data = img.getdata()
    encryptedPixelsList = []
    pixel = []
    if len(data) % 3 != 0:
        data += (3 - (len(data) % 3)) * b'\x00'
    for i, Byte in enumerate(data):
        if i % 3 == 2:
            pixel.append(Byte)
            encryptedPixelsList.append(tuple(pixel))
            pixel = []
        else:
            pixel.append(Byte)

    for _ in range(len(encryptedPixelsList), n**2):
        encryptedPixelsList.append((0, 0, 0))

    img.putdata(encryptedPixelsList)
    imagePath = imagePath.replace('\\', '_')
    img.save(f'./{encryptedImagesFolder}/{imagePath}.png')
    # img.show()


def encode_folder(folder: Path):

    for file in folder.iterdir():
        if not file.is_dir():
            with open(str(file), 'rb') as rb:
                data = rb.readlines()
                encode_data_to_image(
                    data=newLine.join(data),
                    imagePath=str(file))
        else:
            encode_folder(folder=file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ./files is the name of the folder you want to encrypt
    encode_folder(folder=Path(r'./files'))
```

and a Image2FilesDecoder.py

this will iterate through the encrypted images folder and will retrieve its former form (run this in another folder with the encrypted images folder so it won't override the original files folder)

```py
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path

newLine = b'\new\n\rL'

def decode_encrypted_images(folder: Path):

    for pic in folder.iterdir():
        img = Image.open(str(pic))
        data = img.getdata()
        totalData = []
        for pixel in data:
            totalData.extend(list(pixel))
        decryptedData = bytes(totalData)
        try:
            decryptedData = eval(
                decryptedData[:decryptedData.rfind(b'}')+1].decode())
        except:
            decryptedData.replace(b'\\', '')
            decryptedData = eval(
                decryptedData[:decryptedData.rfind(b'}')+1].decode())
        decryptedData['data'] = decryptedData['data'][:-14]

        filePathObj = Path(decryptedData['path'])
        Path(filePathObj.parent).mkdir(
            parents=True, exist_ok=True)

        writeBytes = decryptedData['data'].split(newLine)
        with open(str(filePathObj), 'wb') as wb:
            wb.writelines(writeBytes)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    decode_encrypted_images(folder=Path(
        r".\encryptedImagesFolder"))
```